# Pytorch dynamic amount of Layers?

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I am trying to specify a dynamic amount of layers, which I seem to be doing wrong.
My issue is that when I define the 100 layers here, I will get an error in the forward step.
But when I define the layer properly it works?
Below simplified example

```py
class PredictFromEmbeddParaSmall(LightningModule):
    def __init__(self, hyperparams={'lr': 0.0001}):
        super(PredictFromEmbeddParaSmall, self).__init__()
        #Input is something like tensor.size=[768*100]
        self.TO_ILLUSTRATE = nn.Linear(768, 5)
        self.enc_ref=[]
        for i in range(100):
            self.enc_red.append(nn.Linear(768, 5))
        # gather the layers output sth
        self.dense_simple1 = nn.Linear(5*100, 2)
        self.output = nn.Sigmoid()
    def forward(self, x):
        # first input to enc_red
        x_vecs = []
        for i in range(self.para_count):
            layer = self.enc_red[i]
            # The first dim is the batch size here, output is correct
            processed_slice = x[:, i * 768:(i + 1) * 768]
            # This works and give the out of size 5
            rand = self.TO_ILLUSTRATE(processed_slice)
            #This will fail? Error below
            ret = layer(processed_slice)
            #more things happening we can ignore right now since we fail earlier
```

I get this error when executing "ret = layer.forward(processed_slice)"

> RuntimeError: Expected object of device type cuda but got device type
> cpu for argument #1 'self' in call to _th_addmm

Is there a smarter way to program this? OR solve the error?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use a ModuleList from pytorch instead of a list: https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.nn.ModuleList.html . That is because Pytorch has to keep a graph with all modules of your model, if you just add them in a list they are not properly indexed in the graph, resulting in the error you faced.

Your coude should be something alike:

```py
class PredictFromEmbeddParaSmall(LightningModule):
    def __init__(self, hyperparams={'lr': 0.0001}):
        super(PredictFromEmbeddParaSmall, self).__init__()
        #Input is something like tensor.size=[768*100]
        self.TO_ILLUSTRATE = nn.Linear(768, 5)
        self.enc_ref=nn.ModuleList()                     # << MODIFIED LINE <<
        for i in range(100):
            self.enc_red.append(nn.Linear(768, 5))
        # gather the layers output sth
        self.dense_simple1 = nn.Linear(5*100, 2)
        self.output = nn.Sigmoid()
    def forward(self, x):
        # first input to enc_red
        x_vecs = []
        for i in range(self.para_count):
            layer = self.enc_red[i]
            # The first dim is the batch size here, output is correct
            processed_slice = x[:, i * 768:(i + 1) * 768]
            # This works and give the out of size 5
            rand = self.TO_ILLUSTRATE(processed_slice)
            #This will fail? Error below
            ret = layer(processed_slice)
            #more things happening we can ignore right now since we fail earlier
```

Then it should work all right!

Edit: alternative way.

Instead of using `ModuleList` you can also just use `nn.Sequential`, this allows you to avoid using the `for` loop in the forward pass. That also means that you will not have access to intermediary activations, so that is not the solution for you if you need them.

```py
class PredictFromEmbeddParaSmall(LightningModule):
    def __init__(self, hyperparams={'lr': 0.0001}):
        super(PredictFromEmbeddParaSmall, self).__init__()
        #Input is something like tensor.size=[768*100]
        self.TO_ILLUSTRATE = nn.Linear(768, 5)
        self.enc_ref=[]
        for i in range(100):
            self.enc_red.append(nn.Linear(768, 5))

        self.enc_red = nn.Seqential(*self.enc_ref)       # << MODIFIED LINE <<
        # gather the layers output sth
        self.dense_simple1 = nn.Linear(5*100, 2)
        self.output = nn.Sigmoid()
    def forward(self, x):
        # first input to enc_red
        x_vecs = []
        out = self.enc_red(x)                            # << MODIFIED LINE <<
```

Comment: There is a much simpler solution here: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-create-mlp-model-with-arbitrary-number-of-hidden-layers/13124/6

Comment: Worked for me but note that there is a typo in Seqential -> Sequential

Answer (score 5):

A little bit more adjustable solution which comes down to matter of taste or complexity of your exact situation was posted [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-create-mlp-model-with-arbitrary-number-of-hidden-layers/13124/6).

For applicability I post an generalized version of the code here:

```py
import torch
from torch import nn, optim
from torch.nn.modules import Module
from implem.settings import settings


class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, layers_data: list, learning_rate=0.01, optimizer=optim.Adam):
        super().__init__()
        self.layers = nn.ModuleList()
        self.input_size = input_size  # Can be useful later ...
        for size, activation in layers_data:
            self.layers.append(nn.Linear(input_size, size))
            input_size = size  # For the next layer
            if activation is not None:
                assert isinstance(activation, Module), \
                    "Each tuples should contain a size (int) and a torch.nn.modules.Module."
                self.layers.append(activation)

        self.device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
        self.learning_rate = learning_rate
        self.optimizer = optimizer(params=self.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

    def forward(self, input_data):
        for layer in self.layers:
            input_data = layer(input_data)
        return input_data


# test that the net is working properly 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    data_size = 5
    layer1, layer2 = 10, 10
    output_size = 2
    data = torch.randn(data_size)
    mlp = Model(data_size, [(layer1, nn.ReLU()), (layer2, nn.ReLU()), (output_size, nn.Sigmoid())])
    output = mlp(data)
    print("done")
```